# JPA EntityGraph throws LazyInitializationException outside Transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

As far as I understood, the JPA Entity Graph should be used to load the entities that would otherwise be lazily loaded. My problem is that I'm fetching my referenced LAZY entities by using the entity graph, but when I try to access those fields outside of the `Transactional` method, I'm getting the **LazyInitializationException**. Here is how I tried it.

Here is the table that defines the entity graph.

**UserTable.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NF_USER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "user-entity-graph-with-messages-and-profile-photos",
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "messagesSent"),
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "messagesReceived"),
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "profilePhotos")
        })
public class UserTable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = ProfilePhotoTable.class)
    private Set<ProfilePhotoTable> profilePhotos = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<MessageTable> messagesReceived = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<MessageTable> messagesSent = new HashSet<>();
```

Here is the class that I am using to fetch the entities with the corresponding Entity Graph.

**UserQueryBuilder.java**

```
@Service
public class UserQueryBuilder {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private TypedQuery<E> query;

    public UserQueryBuilder(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = Objects.requireNonNull(entityManager);
    }

    public Optional<E> singleResult() {
        E entity = null;

        try {
            entity = query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            // ignore when no result
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(entity);
    }

    public UserQueryBuilder withMessagesAndProfilePhotos() {
        this.query = query.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", entityManager.getEntityGraph("user-entity-graph-with-messages-and-profile-photos"));
        return this;
    }

    public UserQueryBuilder findById(long id) {
        this.query = entityManager
                .createQuery("SELECT e FROM UserTable e WHERE e.userId = :userId", UserTable.class)
                .setParameter("userId", id);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Here is my DAO class with the Transactional method.

**UserDAO.java**

```
@Service
public class UserDAO {

    @Inject
    private UserQueryBuilder userQueryBuilder;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public UserTable findById(long userId) {
        final UserTable user = userQueryBuilder
                .findById(userId)
                .withMessagesAndProfilePhotos()
                .singleResult()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NonExistingEntityException(
                        String.format("User with ID=%d not found.", userId)));

        return user;
    }
}
```

And here is my business class that tries to access the **LAZY** profile photos property of the user (that should have been obtained by the entity graph).

```
@Service
public class MessageService {

    @Inject
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public void readAllForUser(long userId) {
        final UserTable user = userDAO.findById(userId); 
        user.getProfilePhotos(); // THIS THROWS LAZY INITIALIZATION EXCEPTION
    }
```

So the problem is that when I load the `UserTable` from the database, and try to use it's lazy fields outside of the Transactional method, I am getting the LazyInitializationException. Why is this happening if I'm using the JPA Entity Graph to load the lazy entities?

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to solve this problem?